# How to store a png image returned from an API to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This `API` returns a PNG QR code.
http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=https://www.google.com&size=100x100

Response data format is - image/png
`console.log` (response.data) displays characters like -

> �Bf\u0018I\u0016�9��1�,K�潤�\u0015�T�/�6�\u000f0M�Coj\u0004�����I��o�\u0007�6\fi�<�l��n#\u0011�x���v\u0018B�U�*v\u0018��9�I�%�p��n�3ʂ}�v�\u001e��F�2\u0013�v�\u0013Oe\u000f@\u0004S\r\u0016R�I�p$W\u

I want to store this image in `mongo` collection field which is defined in a schema like below

```
qrCode: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't store the image in your database you store the path to the image in the database and the actual image you store it in a folder in your project

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the png file as a buffer in the mongodb.
you can write something like this:

```
const buffer  = req.file.buffer;  
const qrCode = new qrCode({data:buffer,contentType:"image"}); //create new instance of the model here.
qrCode.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  // saved!
});
```

Comment: this is what I am doing to store buffer
` const qrApiResponse = await axios.get(`http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=${feedbackFormUrl}!&size=200x200`);
                          
        const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(qrApiResponse.data);
      console.log(imageBuffer);
      const image = {
      data: imageBuffer,
      contentType: 'image/png'
    };`

Comment: This should work. you just need to grab the buffer and save it to MongoDB. Inserting any buffer data is as easy as inserting a string or number. but remember inserting buffer to the DB is not a good idea at all. You should consider saving them in your file system and save the address to the DB.